# Hazelcast spring configuration

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast, distributed-cache, hazelcast-imap

Whats the difference between `<hz:map>` tag created in the `applicationContext` vs the one that is defined in the `<hz:config>` segment?

How are they related?

I am aware that `<hz:map>` in `applicationContext` would result in creation of a bean of type IMap and it won't when no `<hz:map>` is there.

But what does the following configuration do when there is a bean defined and subsequently have a `<hz:map>` with same name under hazelcast configuration?

```
<hz:map id="loggedInUserMap" name="loggedInUserMap" instance-ref="ipds" scope="singleton" />
<hz:hazelcast id="ipds">

        <hz:config>

            <hz:instance-name>${hz.instance.name}</hz:instance-name>
            <hz:group name="${hz.group.name}" password="${hz.group.password}"/>

            <hz:map name="loggedInUserMap" backup-count="1" eviction-policy="NONE" in-memory-format="BINARY">
                <hz:near-cache time-to-live-seconds="0" max-idle-seconds="60"
                               eviction-policy="LRU" max-size="5000"  invalidate-on-change="true"/>
            </hz:map>

        </hz:config>

    </hz:hazelcast>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<hz:map id="loggedInUserMap" name="loggedInUserMap" 
            instance-ref="ipds" scope="singleton" />
```

This will result in creation of a bean named 'loggedInUserMap' (pointed by `id` attribute). The name of the map in Hazelcast context will be also "loggedInUserMap" (pointed by `name` attribute).

`A <hz:map>` tag inside `<hz:config>` refers to a specific configuration that can be used while creating an `IMap` (Here by referred to as `MapConfig`). There could be many such `MapConfigs` in a hazelcast.xml. One `MapConfig` can be shared by multiple IMaps as well using wildcard `*`.

If you have a MapConfig with `name` that matches with the map "name" used in hazelcast context, then that configuration will be used while creating that IMap object. In your case it is "loggedInUserMap".

If not found, MapConfig with name "default" will be used to create that IMap object.

If not found, defaults for the IMap will be used while creating that IMap object.

I think the following example will sort things out clearly.

Sample Config

```
<hz:config>
    <hz:instance-name>${hz.instance.name}</hz:instance-name>
    <hz:group name="${hz.group.name}" password="${hz.group.password}"/>

    <hz:map name="default" 
        backup-count="2" max-size="0"
        time-to-live-seconds="25" eviction-percentage="30"
        eviction-policy="NONE"/>

    <hz:map name="userMap" 
        backup-count="2" max-size="0" 
        time-to-live-seconds="6000" eviction-percentage="30"
        eviction-policy="NONE"/>

    <hz:map name="FruitMap*" 
        backup-count="2" max-size="0" 
        time-to-live-seconds="10" eviction-percentage="30"
        eviction-policy="NONE"/>

</hz:config>

<hz:map instance-ref="ipds" id="userMapSpringId" name="userMap" />
<hz:map instance-ref="ipds" id="mangoMapSpringId" name="FruitMap1" />
<hz:map instance-ref="ipds" id="appleMapSpringId" name="FruitMap2" />
<hz:map instance-ref="ipds" id="alientFruitMapSpringId" name="AlienFruit" />
```

Sample code

```
IMap map1 = (IMap) ctx.getBean("userMapSpringId");
// map1 will make use of the configuration with name "userMap"

IMap map2 = (IMap) ctx.getBean("mangoMapSpringId");
IMap map3 = (IMap) ctx.getBean("appleMapSpringId");
// Here two different IMaps objects are created. 
// However both map2 and map3 will make use of the same configuration "FruitMap*". 

IMap map4 = (IMap) ctx.getBean("alientFruitMapSpringId");
// In the case of map4, there is no configuration which matches its hazelcast name 
// (AlienFruit). Hence it will make use of the configuration with name "default".
```

I hope the code snippet with comments are self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks. May be hazelcast guys could amend the xml tags to make it self explanatory.

Comment: True, however renaming xml tags might create compatibility issues (minor though) at this point. However, documentation can be modified to state the facts clearly, may be with an example.